# SQL Server: set NULL value to today's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a column `EntryDate` in a SQL Server database.

How can I set a NULL value to fill it with today's date (server time) if value was not provided in a query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disallow Nulls on the column and set a default on the column of `getdate()`

```
/*Deal with any existing NULLs*/
UPDATE YourTable SET EntryDate=GETDATE() WHERE EntryDate IS NULL

/*Disallow NULLs*/
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN EntryDate DATE NOT NULL

/*Add default constraint*/
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_YourTable_EntryDate DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR EntryDate
```

Comment: This is the best solution. It does have the effect that if the query explicitly provides a NULL for the EntryDate field, the query will error. The query will have to either not specify anything for EntryDate, or specify DEFAULT VALUES.

Comment: best, possibly, but it's not what he's asking for

Comment: @smirkingman - It's ambiguous IMO. Depends on how you interpret "if value was not provided in a query". My answer will add today's date to that column for an insert statement that does not supply a value for `EntryDate` such as `INSERT INTO  [YourTable] (Col1) VALUES ('X')`

Comment: The default constraint by itself answers the question. Martin provided a bit more to address existing data and enforce data integrity.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update table 
set EntryDate = getdate() 
where EntryDate is null
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also, this isn't exactly automatic, like the OP probably expects it to be. Sure - it updates the NULL values to today's date - but that needs to be called explicitly, it doesn't do it automatically when the data gets inserted....

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Rename your table, and create a view with the same name that does the logic you want, i.e.:

```
CREATE VIEW TableName
AS
SELECT Column1, Column2, ... ISNULL(EntryDate, GETDATE())
FROM Old_TableName
```

Then you don't alter your actual data, but if you get a null value for that table it reports today's date.

Comment: this causes the value of EntryDate to behave very different than the other answers.  The question is vague so I'm not sure which is correct.  Using a view will cause the NULL EntryDate columns to always have the current datetime value (which is different each run) as opposed to the UPDATE answers where the NULL EntryDate columns get changed to the current datetime once and then retain that same value for every future select.

Comment: I think this is the right solution, except you have to use COALESCE instead of ISNULL

Comment: @idevlop - why is that?  I have used this logic in SQL Server views before

Comment: That's fine then...simply that I did not know ISNULL existed and I always used COALESCE.

Comment: @idevlop - Gotcha.  `ISNULL` is SQL Server specific, I believe.

Comment: I have often used http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/what-are-the-main-differences-between-access-and-sql-server.html when I need to "translate" from Access to SQL Server, and they propose COALESCE as an equivalent to Access' NZ function. Plus I learned COALESCE when I prepared an MS exam long ago. I must be outdated :/

Comment: **You can't just blindly use one or the other, they are different!** The result of ISNULL() always takes on the datatype of the first parameter (regardless of whether it is NULL or NOT NULL). COALESCE works more like a CASE expression, which returns a single datatype depending on precendence and accommodating all possible outcomes. For example: `DECLARE @foo VARCHAR(5);SET @foo=NULL; SELECT ISNULL(@foo, '123456789');SELECT COALESCE(@foo, '123456789')` see here: http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/coalesce-vs-isnull-sql.html