# Default getdate for Insert date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table called sample and it has a column called [__INSERT_DATE] which is null. Now I want to alter the column with default as `getdate()`. When I tried the following it gave me an error.

```
ALTER TABLE sample
ALTER COLUMN [__INSERT_DATE] [datetime] DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL)
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'.

Comment: You will need to replace all existing `NULL` values in the data and make the column not allow nulls for this to do what you want. My [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315295/sql-server-set-null-value-to-todays-value/4315323#4315323) contains the code to do this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT
DF_MyTable_Inserted DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR INSERT_DATE
GO
```

This assumes your table is named `MyTable`, the column is `INSERT_DATE`, and the name of the contstraint is to be `DF_MyTable_Inserted`

Comment: Does it work with datetime2? It's not working for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE sample ADD CONSTRAINT DF_sample___INSERT_DATE DEFAULT(GETDATE()) FOR __INSERT_DATE
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ALTER TABLE sample ADD INSERT_DATE [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate()
```

This will works in Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) gives this example:

```
ALTER TABLE MyCustomers ALTER COLUMN CompanyName SET DEFAULT 'A. Datum Corporation'
```

That would give you

```
  ALTER TABLE sample ALTER COLUMN __INSERT_DATE SET DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Comment: It gave me the following error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

Comment: @Sam How could something so simple be so complicated!? Do we have the correct name and data type for the Insert Date column? It is a datetime, not a varchar or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it using SSManagement Studio

[image: Setting default in SSMS - Screen Shot]

make the date field not nullable, then from properties
set Defalut Value or Binding to  getdate()

Comment: This works great, however is there a way to also have it use `getdate()` again when the row has been updated?

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE sample
ALTER COLUMN [__INSERT_DATE] [datetime] DEFAULT (getdate()) NULL)`

You have one too many closing brackets in the above statement. There are 2 of these -> ( but 3 of these -> )

Answer (score 1):

[image]

(Your_Date_Column) Make it Null / Not Null and give default value GetDate() but still it will not work.
You have to create a trigger like this,

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_Date]
    ON [dbo].[TableName]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN

```
    Declare @Id int
    set @Id = (select Id from inserted)

    Update [dbo].[TableName]
    Set Your_Date_Column = GetDate()
    Where Id = @Id
END
```

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me:

```
ALTER TABLE sample ALTER COLUMN INSERT_DATE [datetime] NULL DEFAULT GetDate()
```

If you already have values in the column, you can do something like this:

```
Alter Table sample add INSERT_DATE_TEMP [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate()
Update sample
SET INSERT_DATE_TEMP = INSERT_DATE
Alter Table sample Drop Column INSERT_DATE
exec sp_rename 'sample.INSERT_DATE_TEMP','INSERT_DATE','COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

Does getdate() return the correct date and time datatype for your declared column?  There are some new date and time datatypes in SQL Server 2008.

Here's an article that explains some of the differences.

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/datetime_2008_p1.aspx

Comment: The OP is on 2005 (from the tags)

Comment: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dev/datetime_2008_p1.aspx not found