# Insert current date into a date column using T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to insert a date when a user decides to deactivate or activate an UserID. I'm trying to use a SP to trigger that but apparantly this is harder than I thought it would be.

I can do a

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

to get the date but is there a way to insert that information from GETDATE and put it into a column I want?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Couple of ways. Firstly, if you're adding a row each time a [de]activation occurs, you can set the column default to GETDATE() and not set the value in the insert. Otherwise,

```
UPDATE TableName SET [ColumnName] = GETDATE() WHERE UserId = @userId
```

Comment: Yea I can leave it blank. I'll try that.

Answer (score 11):

To insert a new row into a given table (tblTable) :

```
INSERT INTO tblTable (DateColumn) VALUES (GETDATE())
```

To update an existing row :

```
UPDATE tblTable SET DateColumn = GETDATE()
 WHERE ID = RequiredUpdateID
```

Note that when `INSERT`ing a new row you will need to observe any constraints which are on the table - most likely the `NOT NULL` constraint - so you may need to provide values for other columns eg...

```
 INSERT INTO tblTable (Name, Type, DateColumn) VALUES ('John', 7, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE Table
SET DateColumn=GETDATE()
WHERE UserID=@UserID
```

If you're inserting into a table, and will always need to put the current date, I would recommend setting `GETDATE()` as the default value for that column, and don't allow NULLs

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to store the information in a table, you need to use an INSERT or an UPDATE statement. It sounds like you need an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE  SomeTable
SET     SomeDateField = GETDATE()
WHERE   SomeID = @SomeID
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use getdate() in a default as this [SO question's accepted answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672103/default-getdate-for-insert-date). This way you don't provide the date, you just insert the rest and that date is the default value for the column.

You could also provide it in the values list of your insert and do it manually if you wish.