# Triggering a timestamp update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamics-crm-2011

**For every INSERT, how do I populate my DateStamp field with the current datetime?**

I've created an error output table for my SSIS task:

[image]

Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[gbs_CRMErrorOutput](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ErrorColumn] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [CrmErrorMessage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [targetid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [subordinateid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [DateStamp] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Please note that I do not have an auto-increment or any key in the table.

I'm also wondering what would be a best practice for this?

Comment: Why do you have a guid but no key? I would not put your clustered index on that column but you could make that your primary key easily enough. For the "DateStamp" issue (I would suggest a better name like DateInserted) you can make the column NOT NULL with a default of GetDate and then in your insert don't insert into that column.

Comment: no key yet, ill create one if i need to, the table shouldnt exceed like 1000 records, the GUIDs will not be unique, they are captured to tell me whats wrong with records from other tables

Comment: @SeanLange ooooh!! you are saying set it to getdate() so that everytime there's an insert, it will just put the date in there? how would i default it to getdate() ? i do not have an INSERT statement in that table, it comes directly from OLEDB

Comment: @SeanLange that's a freakin awesome idea. make that an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of using not null with a default. In your real table you may want to name your default constraint. If you define the constraint inline like this it will still be named but it will be automatically assigned.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
MyID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
SomeValue VARCHAR(10),
DateCreated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

INSERT #MyTable(SomeValue)
VALUES ('Value1')

--This next line just waits for 1 second. 
--This will demonstrate multiple inserts at different times so you can the values change

WAITFOR DELAY '00:0:01'

INSERT #MyTable(SomeValue)
VALUES ('Value2')

SELECT *
FROM #MyTable

DROP TABLE #MyTable
```

Comment: why are we waiting for a delay?

Answer (score 1):

Two good options:

1) Create a DEFAULT CONSTRAINT on your table with GETDATE() specified for your column ([good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672103/default-getdate-for-insert-date)).  Within SSIS, do not map any value to that column - leave it as Ignore.  Make sure that Keep Nulls is not checked.   Note that you might have to fiddle with the settings of your OLE DB Destination - uncheck Identity Insert if there's a problem.  I've also seen cases where the column had to allow NULLs - that only affects certain scenarios.

2) Add a Derived Column transformation to your data flow, setting it up to add a new column to the flow.  I usually use the System::StartTime variable here, so that all records inserted during a single ETL run will share the same inserted date, but you could just as easily use the SSIS function GETDATE().
[image: SSIS Derived Column Transformation Editor]

Map the new column you just created to your OLE DB Destination.