# Can dateupdated get date from db?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain with a dateupdated field, this is autocompleted by hibernate with the current date from the system, but my project is running in several machines and in order to keep consistence, I need to get this value from the database. Unfortunately I can't use triggers.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer:[Default getdate for Insert date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672103/default-getdate-for-insert-date)

You should use GetDate() as DEFAULT VALUE for the field in the table, with this you don't need trigger or something similar.